# Javascript Animate ScrollTop Jumps to Top of Window, Then Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I've got a WordPress menu item with Javascript successfully attached, and I'm trying to make it scroll to the bottom of the page when clicked on.  The scrolling itself worked fine, but I found that the page would jump up to the top for a fraction of a second before scrolling down to the bottom.  That code looked like this:

```
$("#menu-item-135").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()}, 500); 
});
```

I googled around for a solution, and ended up with this

```
$("#menu-item-135").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()}, 500); 
    return false;
});
```

All I did was add 'return false;'.  That solved the jumping to the top problem, but now the page jumps to the bottom before scrolling instead!  Does anyone have any other ideas for what I might try?

Comment: Can you provide an example in jsFiddle or something?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do that, unfortunately.  It's a WordPress site so I've got a lot of calls to WP-specific functions that are necessary for the relevant code to display correctly

Comment: Well this is odd.  It just randomly started working correctly by itself.  All I did was remove <?php wp_footer(); ?> from the footer and then put it back...  and whatever I did seems to have fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

you need to try this.